Activating the flash when starting a camera in Camera.MAUI crashes on Android
I am developing a .NET MAUI App that uses the phone's camera to take pictures and to scan barcodes. I use the Camera.MAUI NuGet package for it and it works fine in most instances. But I have one particular issue with a new requirement: The flash shall be turned on when the user switches into the camera view. It works fine on iOS, but crashes on Android.
What I do
XAML
        xmlns:camera="clr-namespace:Camera.MAUI;assembly=Camera.MAUI"

        <camera:CameraView x:Name="CameraView"
                           WidthRequest="360" 
                           HeightRequest="240"
                           Margin="0,20,0,0"
                           CamerasLoaded="CameraViewCamerasLoaded"
                           BarCodeDetectionEnabled="True"
                           TorchEnabled="{Binding Path=UseFlash}"
                           FlashMode="Enabled"
                           BarcodeDetected="CameraViewBarcodeDetected" />

Code behind
    private void CameraViewCamerasLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CameraView.Cameras.Count > 0)
        {
            CameraView.Camera = CameraView.Cameras.First();

            MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                await CameraView.StopCameraAsync();
                await CameraView.StartCameraAsync();

                _viewModel.InitializeCamera();
            });
        }
    }

View Model
    public bool UseFlash
    {
        get { return _useFlash; }
        set { SetValue(ref _useFlash, value); }
    }

    private bool _useFlash;

    public void InitializeCamera()
    {
        var deviceService = _serviceProvider.GetService<IDeviceService>();
        if (deviceService != null)
        {
            UpdateFlash(deviceService.GetDefaultCameraFlashState());
        }
    }

    private void UpdateFlash(bool useFlash)
    {
        UseFlash = useFlash;

        if (_flashButton != null)
        {
            if (!UseFlash)
            {
                _flashButton.Caption = _translationService.Get("global_syn_patrol_enable_camera_flash");
            }
            else
            {
                _flashButton.Caption = _translationService.Get("global_syn_patrol_disable_camera_flash");
            }
        }
    }

Explanation
What I do is pretty straightforward: The camera's flash in the View is bound to the UseFlash property of the View Model. When the camera is loaded, CameraViewCamerasLoaded is executed which (re-)initializes the camera on the main thread and initializes the View Model. In the View Model, the default setting for camera flash is read and set to the UseFlash property.
Android vs. iOS
On iOS it works exactly as expected. When I switch to the camera module, the flash activates, when the setting is set.
On Android, I get the following exception:
System.NullReferenceException
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The Stack Trace is
0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF in Android.Runtime.RuntimeNativeMethods.monodroid_debugger_unhandled_exception   C#
0x1A in Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper._unhandled_exception at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:13,5 C#
0x1D in Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PP_V at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:27,26    C#
0x17 in System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw    C#
0x6 in System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__128_0 C#
0xC in Android.App.SyncContext. at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.App/SyncContext.cs:36,19 C#
0xE in Java.Lang.Thread.RunnableImplementor.Run at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Java.Lang/Thread.cs:36,6 C#
0x8 in Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/net8.0/android-34/mcw/Java.Lang.IRunnable.cs:84,4    C#
0x8 in Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PP_V at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:26,5  C#

I tried to research the issue online but without success. Does anyone have an idea?

which line of code or action in your app triggers the crash?

The App crashes when the property is set: UseFlash = useFlash; Because of the binding, this should active the Flash, but instead the App crashes on Adroid. Again, on iOS everything works. I can toggle the Flash via button during run-time using the same function without any issues. It just does not work right at the beginning.

https://github.com/hjam40/Camera.MAUI/issues?q=torchenabled
